# issue instaling adobe air on fedora 17

Tags: fedora, adobe-air

I'm Trying to intall adobe air on my Fedora 17 gnome I've Downloaded my Adobeair.bin File when a run the File I got this.

```
/tmp/air.IAduL7/setup: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Nice When I try to Install libgtk I got this

```
yum install -y ld-linux.so.2 gtk2-devel.i686 libdbus-glib-1.so.2 libhal.so.1
```

I got another error

```
Error: Protected multilib versions: 
dbus-glib-0.98-2.fc17.i686 != dbus-glib-0.92-3.fc17.x86_64
```